# How to properly handle WebCamTexture in Compute Shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compute-shader, color-space

I've been working on a piece of code that utilizes WebCamTexture and Compute Shader to copy its data onto a RenderTexture. The Compute Shader's primary task is to perform a straightforward operation of copying pixel values from WebCamTexture to RenderTexture. While this approach works correctly on some devices, it appears darker on others.

To address the issue of the darker output, I initially modified the Color Space to Gamma, which did resolve the problem to some extent, but it wasn't the ideal solution I was looking for. Suspecting that the Color Space might be the cause, I attempted to find a method to determine whether the WebCamTexture's format is sRGB, but I couldn't find the correct approach.

After numerous trial-and-error attempts, I eventually discovered that changing the RenderTexture's format to 'ARGBFloat' resolves the problem. Here's the code snippet I used:

`mRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(mTexture2D.width, mTexture2D.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat);`

Now, my questions are as follows:

1. Can you explain the underlying principle behind the solution of changing the RenderTexture's format to 'ARGBFloat' and how it resolved the issue?
2. Is this solution the correct approach? Does it cover all potential scenarios and remain efficient?

I would greatly appreciate your insights and assistance in addressing these questions. Thank you.